# Appending by name with python pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am tryining to append a pandas multiindex dataframe within a loop.

My multiindex dataframe looks a little like this (let's call it df1):

```
method     (TestAa, TestAb)
properties level     l      r
0          0.0   144.6  161.4
1          0.1   146.3  161.4
2          0.2   148.0  161.4
3          0.3   149.7  161.4
4          0.4   151.3  161.4
```

Now I want to append another dataframe (df2) to it, so that the appended dataframe is sorted by the name "method" (which btw is a string tuple). In my mind it should look like that:

```
method     (TestAa, TestAb)     /  (TestBa, TestBb)                   
properties level       l      r /  level       l      r
0            0.0   144.6  161.4 /    0.0   150.6  161.4
1            0.1   146.3  161.4 /    0.1   151.3  161.4
2            0.2   148.0  161.4 /    0.2   152.0  161.4
3            0.3   149.7  161.4 /    0.3   153.7  161.4
4            0.4   151.3  161.4 /    0.4   155.3  161.4
```

In other words I want to add another column to an existing dataframe.

Right now I am creating the df as described in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/advanced.html):

```
method = tuple([TestAa, TestAb])
columns = [[method]*3,["level", "l", "r"]]
tuples = list(zip(*columns))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['method', 'properties'])
df1= pd.DataFrame(columns=index, data=data, dtype=np.float)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I believe need only [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: You had a missing letter in your link

Comment: @zipa - Thank you.

Comment: thank you! I just found out, that if you loop it, I can save my dataframes in a list and then mesh them together to a single multiindex dataframe with pd.concat(df_list). Just wanted to chare my realisation. cheers for the help!